# jQuery Sortable - nested sorting breaks with position relative list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm having an issue with jQuery Sortable, https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/

Currently the reordering / sorting of this plugin breaks when position relative is added to the list items. This can be reproduced easily on the demo page if you just add position relative to the `<li>` elements in the your web inspector.

Top level reordering / sorting works just fine, but nested reordering breaks.

I've created a fiddle of the problem, try moving a top-level item in the right-side list into a nested position, it breaks: http://jsfiddle.net/0ogreec0/1/

Could anybody help with this please? I've tried fiddling with the JS code but it's quick advanced stuff. Massive thanks in advance to anyone that might be able to help!

Comment: what exactly is broken about it?

Comment: Try the fiddle - drag the first item of the list on the right, it won't allow dropping in the nested part of the list. On the left side, it works. @jmore009

Comment: I see, is there a reason you want to add `position: relative`?

Comment: Yep, in my app there's a small controls bar for each 'list item' that contains the drag handle, duplicate and delete buttons inside; this is position absolute and I believe needs to be unfortunately (it needs to float on top and not alter the layout). @jmore009